# Clear the label messages at the time of choosing the file using file uploader

Tags: css, asp.net, file-upload

Below is my aspx page code which contains a file uploader and I need to remove the label messages while choosing the file it self. 
How can I do this?

```html
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>
```

I tried this with the events for fileuploader but they are not working.

Comment: Not really relevant to your question but you didnt close your `<tr>`

Comment: have you tried using `onchange` on fileupload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `onchange` on to fileupload

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  onchange="callme();" />
```

and then, create a JS function to clear your messages

```
function callme() {
         document.getElementById("your message label id").value= "";
       }
```

I didn't test, but this should do what you want.

Comment: It is working fine but the problem is again if i choose the file if it is not a valid document it should show the error message but it is not showing anything

Comment: in this case, update the function to accept the file upload as parameter... `onchange="callme(this);"` and change function signature to `function callme(objFile){}` then you can access the file name but I don't remember by heart now...I think objFile.value get the full path and objFile.files[0].name gives you just the name...with this, you just need to validate when you want do remove the label message. Hope it's clear.

Comment: how to do that can you please show that as i am new to this

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny1zdq4b/), just adapt according your needs ;-)